# How is the lack of the "SameSite" cookie flag a risk?

Tags: web-application, http, cookies, websites, same-origin-policy

Nowadays cookies can have HTTPOnly, Secure and SameSite flags. The purposes of HTTPOnly and Secure flags are pretty clear. But what does SameSite scripting prevent exactly and how?

Additionally, how would a scenario of successful "attacking" or "misusing" look like when the SameSite flag is not used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The goals of the [SameSite](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07#section-1.1) flag are:

- prevent cross-site timing attacks (see eg [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170424225805/https://www.contextis.com/documents/2/Browser_Timing_Attacks.pdf))
- prevent cross-site script inclusion (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028511/what-is-cross-site-script-inclusion-xssi))
- prevent CSRF: SameSite cookies are only sent if the site the request originated from is in the same site as the target site (in strict mode for GET and POST, in lax mode only for POST requests).
- limited privacy protection

Answer (score 8):

The actual answer should be, as always: it depends on your usage scenario.

The `Strict` value will prevent the cookie from being sent by the browser
to the target site in all cross-site browsing context, even when following a regular
link. For example, for a GitHub-like website this would mean that if a logged-in user
follows a link to a private GitHub project posted on a corporate discussion forum
or email, GitHub will **not** receive the session cookie and the user will not be able
to access the project. A bank website however most likely doesn't want
to allow any transactional pages to be linked from external sites so the `Strict` flag
would be most appropriate here.

The default `Lax` value provides a reasonable balance between security
and usability for websites that want to maintain user's logged-in session after
the user arrives from an external link. In the above GitHub scenario, the session cookie
would be allowed when following a regular link from an external website while blocking
it in CSRF-prone request methods (e.g. `POST`).

Comment: Note that the value should be `Strict` or `Lax` with a capital first letter according to the draft found at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07

Comment: @jlh I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @jlh according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-02#section-5.3.7 All of `SameSite`, `Strict` and `Lax` use case-insensitive match, as usual for HTTP headers.